# Adding counts from one dataframe to another dataframe on corresponding row

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

I would like to count the number of record in **dataframe2** and add the count to the corresponding rows in **dataframe1**.

##### The first one (df1)

| Road | RoadNo | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0 |
| A | 2 | 0 |
| B | 1 | 0 |
| B | 2 | 0 |

##### The second one (df2)

| Road | RoadNo |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 1 |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 2 |
| B | 1 |

The expected output is to count the number of records in **dataframe2** and add that number to the corresponding Road and RoadNo rows in **dataframe1**.

##### Expected Output:

| Road | RoadNo | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 3 |
| A | 2 | 2 |
| B | 1 | 1 |
| B | 2 | 0 |

Is there a function in Pandas or Python that can help me with this operation? Do I need to create two tables in the database and execute the SQL query to perform this operation? Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first count the values from `df2` for all `Road` and `RoadNo` pairs and then join the resulting data frame to `df1`:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={"Road":["A", "A", "B", "B"],   "RoadNo": [1, 2, 1, 2], "Count":[0, 0, 0, 0]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={"Road":["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B"], "RoadNo": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1]})


merge_df = df2.value_counts(["Road", "RoadNo"]).reset_index().rename(columns={0: "Count"})
expected_df = pd.merge(left=df1.drop(columns=["Count"]), right=merge_df, on=["Road", "RoadNo"], how="left").fillna(0).astype({"Count": "int32"})
expected_df

---------------------------------
    Road RoadNo Count
0   A    1      3
1   A    2      2
2   B    1      1
3   B    2      0
---------------------------------
```